# Unable to find the np-install for nebular

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, nebular

I am getting this compiler error.  Can someone tell me which nebular module I need to install to fix this?

```
    Failed to compile.

./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!
./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)

 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
 @include nb-install() { ^ No mixin named nb-install in /Users/denisputnam/git/nb-niche-app/src/styles.scss (line 7, column 10)
```

Comment: Did you add `"node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/corporate.scss"` in your styles array of `angular.json`

Comment: No, I had not.  Thank you.

Comment: Adding that helped?

Comment: Yes it did.  Not sure why, but I will take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `"node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/corporate.scss"` in your styles array of angular.json

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it seemed to fix it. then all of a sudden i got more compiler errors.  I obviously have not idea of what I am doing.  I don't suppose you know of a good tutorial on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have restored things and cannot reproduce the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following the official docs on this https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/enable-theme-system#basic-setup. In the simplest configuration, the only thing you need to do is to add a single css file to your `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/@nebular/theme/styles/prebuilt/corporate.css",
],
```

In a case when you need more flexibility on this (for example being able to change theme SCSS variables) - follow the `Normal` setup guide here https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/guides/enable-theme-system#normal-setup.

But it is hard to tell more as the question description doesn't give a lot of details on what you are trying to achieve.